# Decide whether a sequence converges or not

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

There is a sequence $(a_{n})_n$ defined by relation: 
$a_{1} = 3 $

$2^{a_2} = 3^3$

$2^{2^{a_{3}}} = 3^{3^{3}}$

$2^{2^{2^{a_{4}}}} = 3^{3^{3^3}}$

Does $(a_{n})_n$ converge?

So, I've tried to figure out what is an overall pattern for $(a_{n})_n$.

I did something like that:

$a_1 = 3$

$2^{a_2} = 3^3$

$\log2^{a_2} = \log3^3$

$a_{2}\log2 = 3\log3$

$a_{2} = 3\frac{\log3}{\log2}$

But I don't know if it gets me anywhere, because I got

$a_3 = \log(\frac{27}{2}\frac{\log3}{\log2})$

Have you got any idea?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the difference between $a_n$ and $(a_n)_n$

Comment: It's just $a_n$

Comment: The sequence is increasing, because $2^{2^{2^{a_3}}}=2^{3^{3^3}}<3^{3^{3^3}}=2^{2^{2^{a_4}}}$ and so on.

Comment: Is 'decide' in the tittle the right word?

Answer (score 1):

The convergence is fairly easy to prove. Let $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_{n+1}(x)=2^{f_n(x)}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n>0$. Then $f_{n+1}'(x)=f_{n+1}(x)f_n'(x)\log 2$, and we see that both $f_n(x)$ and $f_n'(x)$ are nondecreasing (i.e. $f_n$ is convex) in $x$ for every $n$, and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/f_n'(x)$ converges *at least* for $x\geqslant 0$.

The given sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies $f_{n+1}(a_{n+1})=3^{f_n(a_n)}$. Replacing $n$ by $n+1$ and taking $\log_2$ twice, $$f_n(a_{n+2})=f_n(a_{n+1})+c,\qquad c=\log_2\log_2 3.$$ Now the convexity of $f_n$ gives $f_n(a_{n+2})\geqslant f_n(a_{n+1})+(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})f_n'(a_{n+1})$, i.e. $$0\leqslant a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}\leqslant\frac{c}{f_n'(a_{n+1})}\leqslant\frac{c}{f_n'(3)},$$ thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})$ converges. Which implies the convergence of $\{a_n\}$ as expected.

*Much more interesting is the question what the limit is. Does it arise anywhere else?..*

Comment: Its first digits are $5.4415643575738$ but it isn't listed at OEIS.